# US/EU dual citizen, move to the Netherlands while working for US company

Tags: immigration, us-citizens, eu-citizens, netherlands, dual-citizenship

I work remotely for a US company and am currently located in Houston. I am an American citizen.

I happen to have a Spanish citizenship, hence am also a EU citizen.

How feasible would it be to continue working for my company and just move to the Netherlands?

Comment: Does your company have payroll in the Netherlands?  If not, you'll probably need to set yourself up as an independent contractor.